# Elements in canvas disappear

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'd like to use a canvas with a table inside. But unfortunately no element is displayed, if it is inside the canvas. If I move it outfide, it works perfectly fine.

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
 }
```

```html
<canvas>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>value 1</td>
      <td>value 2</td>
      <td>value 3</td>
      <td>value 4</td>
      <td>value 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</canvas>
```

Comment: This isn't how canvas is intended to be used. The stuff you put inside the tags is only shown as a fallback if canvas isn't supported by a browser. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @ggorlen so to use the canvas correctly, I have to move the elements out of it?

Comment: @TomMaximilianMüller Typically, the only thing that goes inside a `<canvas>` tag is whatever you want to display if the user's browser cannot display canvas. In most canvas tutorials, you'll see a message similar to "Sorry, your browser does not support Canvas" nested in Canvas tags. That message will only display if the user's browser can't/won't display canvas elements.

Comment: @Tanner Thanks for this advice :).

Comment: @TomMaximilianMüller It depends on what you're trying to accomplish and what you mean by "correctly". Do you want to create a table? If so, get rid of the canvas tags. Do you want to draw stuff on a canvas? If so, get rid of the table tags. Your current code is correct--the table will be shown to users of browsers that don't support canvas. If that's what you intended, you're all set.

Comment: @ggorlen I use some animation on the page (inside the canvas) and on this canvas, the table should get displayed.

Comment: OK, please post that in your question. See [mcve]. Quoting from that: "tell other readers what the expected behavior should be".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like ggorlen pointed out, that's not how the canvas-element is intended to be used. Rather make a container element and put both the canvas and the table in it.

An example would be:

```html
<div style="position: relative;">
    <canvas style="position: absolute;">
    </canvas>

    <table style="position: absolute;">
        <tr>
            <td>value 1</td>
            <td>value 2</td>
            <td>value 3</td>
            <td>value 4</td>
            <td>value 5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

That just puts the table above the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas isn't like classic html elements. It is intended as place to draw graphics and animations.

If you must use html element into canvas, it isn't possible in direct way, but you may use some API to render html elements into canvas (Like: [rasterizeHTML](https://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/) - have example on page).

But you should read something a basic canvas usege [w3schools canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_drawing.asp).

Or check live examples about what is possible with canvas (for example with [fabric.js](http://fabricjs.com/) API) and some other demos with canvas to have slight brief about canvas usage.